# Sound volume icon (volume control widget) disappears from tray and Fn-F11/Fn-F12 keys do not work

Tags: 17.10, plasma

After some time working with the system volume icon is no longer in the system tray and <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd> / <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> do not work.

Restarting `plasmashell` does not fix the problem.

How do I restore it back without restarting the system or re-login? At least having some workaround would be nice.

Comment: Why got this question down-voted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that the issue was that `plasma-pa` package was missing.
I guess it got uninstalled for some reason.

Reinstalling it and restarting plasmashell fixes the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install plasma-pa
killall plasmashell
plasmashell &
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed my audio issue since upgrading to Kubuntu 17.10, where the audio volume keys wouldn't control any audio anymore, but only showing the audio OSD,

Comment: TY Man. I have same issue and this solution fixed my problem.

Comment: helped me after 4 years, after i messed up things while trying to enable mic support using pipewire + pulseaudio!