# Crackling/delayed sound from ALC892 Digital device on Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, 18.04, pulseaudio

My digital audio device is producing crackling and delayed sounds. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with KDE desktop. The available audio devices are listed below:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
Subdevices: 0/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I would like to point out, that it is only the digital device causing problems. Headphones or speakers connected via analog audio jacks on the front of my case work fine.

I tried the suggested solutions from
[Crackling and delayed sound after upgrading to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033405/crackling-and-delayed-sound-after-upgrading-to-18-04)
but they did not work out for me. In the linked question the crackling appears with front AND back audio ports. So for me it seems to be a different issue. Do have any idea?

Comment: In the meantime, I move forward to Kubuntu 20.04 LTS.  About 2 weeks ago, this crackling and delayed sounds also appeared for my analog outputs.

In order to solve this, I completely purged `pulseaudio` which cured my disturbed audio but removed the volume control panel from my system tray. After days of research and a gazillion of failed repair attempts, I found out that `plasma_pa` was uninstalled during the purge of `pulseaudio`. I found the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/997334/sound-volume-icon-volume-control-widget-disappears-from-tray-and-fn-f11-fn-f12